# How to (intentionally) skip an app with Django syncdb

Tags: django, django-models, django-south

I have several django applications:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'geonode.exposure',
    'geonode.isc_viewer',
    'geonode.geodetic',
    'geonode.observations',
    'geonode.ged4gem',
```

I need to manage all of them except one with `syncdb`. 
How can I get `syncdb` to intentionally skip the `geonode.exposure` application?

**Update:**
I did not describe the full configuration, please allow me to go into more detail:
I am using south to manage db migrations and fixtures for all the apps except exposure.
The exposure app is accessing an external database and is using a router to do so (this is why I want it to be skipped by syncdb).
My router settings look like this:

```
class GedRouter(object):
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        "Point all operations on ged models to 'geddb'"
        if model._meta.app_label == 'exposure':
            return 'geddb'
        return 'default'

    def allow_syncdb(self, db, model):
        if db == 'geddb' or model._meta.app_label == "ged":
            return False # we're not using syncdb on our legacy database
        else: # but all other models/databases are fine
            return True
```

Is south not respecting the allow_syncdb method? is south running syncbd on the exposure app because I do not have a migration for it?

Comment: You could try removing the ``__init__.py`` file from the folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `managed = False` in the model's `Meta` class. This way, syncdb won't create the app's tables. More information on the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#managed).

Comment: I thought it worked, but after looking a bit closer, no dice. I have also tried removing the models.py all together, but syncdb gives me: django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: ImportError geonode.exposure: No module named exposure

Comment: You could also remove the app from settings.py, then syncdb and add the app again. What failed from my solution?

Answer (score 1):

There is a model meta option "managed", for more info check django documentation:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#managed

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is not what your asking directly, but please consider using South http://south.aeracode.org

You can decided which apps to include which version of the model to migrate etc. Sounds like you need a solution here.